# Using firebase with 000WebHost

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-hosting

Can I use firebase with a free web server host like 000webhost? If yes, how can I do it?

I need to implement some server code in php which is being hosted on 000webhost. I need my php code to talk to a firebase database. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this really should go to the web host support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible with the [Firebase Admin SDK for PHP](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

000webhost runs PHP7 so you should be good to go.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying :-) I just need some steps to start with. Im very new to this so I'm a little confused. It would be great if you could just some basic steps to start with. Help would be very much appreciated :-)